# How can I apply for an R&D position with not-so-excellent thesis?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, research

I am currently a Master's course student and applying for my desired position of R&D at a large company. It seems that they highly pay attention to the final research (on the online application form, they spend a quite large amount of characters to fill in that field).

Although I am still in my last semester and haven't finished my final thesis, and it is not so horrible, I am sure it wouldn't be what I want to mention when it comes to an interview because of the theme I have chosen (I was kinda stuck when I needed to pick a topic, so my professor told me just to consider it an "exercise" - and I did). Instead, I spent most of my time doing an internship at a company, where I did gain some valuable relevant experience.

I think I might be wrong with that decision, so I would appreciate any advice how to fix that - how to tell the interviewer about my not-so-good research during my study?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on Academia?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Academia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different people judge the same thing in different ways.

You should do the most simple thing.

1. Decide if you really want that job.
2. If yes, apply for it, regardless of what you think about your thesis.

Instead of focusing on what is "less than perfect", you should find the selling points of it, and sell yourself as good as possible.

If you feel there are other aspects more important than the thesis, present them with emphasis, and let the employer bring the thesis under discussion.